# How to manually expire Play 2 cache

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, ehcache

Per Play 2 [article](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaCache), there are ways to set a cache including a timeout on the cache (in the API spec), however I need the ability to manually expire the entire cache as needed, is there a way to do that? In particular, I am using `Cached`, not `Cache` to cache the HTTP response as such

```
  def get(key: String) = Cached("key-" + key, duration = 3600) {
    Action {
      Ok(some_method)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

In play2.1 you can do `Cache.remove("item.key")`

It isn't a major to upgrade to RC1 and seems just as stable as 2.0.4.

Comment: Good idea except I'm not using 2.1 yet.

Answer (score 2):

Current cache API of Play 2 is... very synthetic.

It seems that the only way (that I'm also using) is setting `null` value for `0` seconds:

```
Cache.set("item.key", null, 0)
```

**Edit**

Actually in Java **Cached** API never worked for me well, don't know why, maybe I overlooked something, so I'm using common `Cache` in the action for caching its `Result`

```
public static Result index() {
    Result cachedResult = (Result) Cache.get("applicationIndex");
    if (cachedResult == null) {
        Result res = ok(index.render("Ready " + Math.random()));
        Cache.set("applicationIndex", res, 5);
        cachedResult = res;
    }
    return cachedResult;
}
```

So using previous sample, you can invalidate it with:

```
Cache.set("applicationIndex", null, 0)
```

Comment: It works in 2.0.x however as Ivan mentioned it's better to build new application with Play 2.1 and its new possibilities in mind. Most probably dev team will release stable version (just my hope) before next serie of apps will go to life :)

Comment: Actually this doesn't work with my code, I am using `Cached`, not `Cache`. See updated question.

Comment: Well, actually did you verify that `Cached` API works at all? check my edit. I don't know the situation in Scala.

Comment: Yes `Cached` API works great until I tried to use `Cache.set`, will try your new approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this play [memcached module](https://github.com/mumoshu/play2-memcached) and run your own [memcached server](http://www.couchbase.com/memcached).  That has an api to manually expire the entire cache.  In production this setup also gives you the extra benefits of having a cache that persists restarts and some helpful cache stats.

Answer (score 0):

in case you still have problems invalidating with 'Cached' instead of 'Cache' try these two lines of code:

```
Cache.remove("item.key")
Cache.remove("item.key" + "-etag")
```

Cached needs the '-etag' cache object also to be removed.